# Python minidom hangs PySide application

Tags: python, xml, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm making an application using PySide. I have a directory tree widget which should list the directory view with certain predefined depth. Mostly these folders will be from a server location. I'm using glob module to list folders with predefined depth. And I build an xml document with this directory list using minidom module which will be later used to build items in tree widget.
But at some point my app freezes and turns out to be non responsive. Here is my code.

```
import glob, os
from xml.dom import minidom
dirs = []
limit = 3
root = "S:/assets"
for i in range(1, limit + 1):
    depth = []
    [depth.append(
        os.path.abspath(x)) for x in glob.glob(
        root + "/*" * i)]
    for each in depth:
        if "." not in os.path.split(each)[-1]:
            dirs.append(each)
dirs.sort()

def showDirectory(base, dirs):
    dirDict = {}
    doc = minidom.Document()
    root = doc.createElement("root")
    for each in dirs:
        items = os.path.split(each)
        if items[-1] == "":
            continue
        elm = doc.createElement("dir")
        elm.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(items[-1]))
        par = os.path.split(items[0])[-1]
        dirDict[items[-1]] = elm
        if os.path.abspath(items[0]) == os.path.abspath(base):
            dirDict[items[-1]] = root.appendChild(elm)
        else:
            dirDict[par].appendChild(elm) # this line is the problem
    doc.appendChild(root)
    return doc

# test
with open("D:/test.xml", "w") as f:
    showDirectory(root, dirs).writexml(f)
```

Problem is not with my app as the same tree widget is being used in many other scenario. If I comment the line I marked as problematic, everything works just fine.

Am I doing something wrong? Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Just a side note: I find generating a whole XML document as an intermediate step for populating your widget not to be a very good design decision. That said you wrote that you use the same tree widget in other projects - do you also do the XML stuff there or is it just here? When stuff hangs it's usually some hidden (or visible) infinite loop or just something that takes too much time to be processed and basically breaks the event system of the application. I would definitely consider using a separate thread to do all this (you can use `QRunnable` since it's a one time thing).

Comment: @rbaleksandar, yes I do use the XML method in certain other areas. But I encounter this problem only when it comes to server resources. Anyway, as per your suggestion, i have removed the xml way of populating tree widget. Now it works fine. 
But there wasn't an infinite loop in the code, just commenting this line *dirDict[par].appendChild(elm)* used to work. Maybe building XML document took a long process time. 
I should have thought of avoiding this way of doing stuff. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Just because you don't see the infinite loop in your code doesn't mean that it doesn't occur somewhere else. But I'm glad it worked out. XML is too much of a fuss to parse and it's definitely no the optimal solution for storage. Also speed-wise writing and reading stuff from your drive is slower (in general) compared to doing the same IO operations but with RAM.

Comment: Generating the data structure that will be used for populating the tree widget should not be done in the same thread as the UI especially if you don't know how many files you have in your target that you have to show in your widget. Yes, even when doing all this in a separate thread smooth results may or may not be present but it's definitely to have a dedicated thread for this (or multiple if your logic allows it) then having everything done in the main thread where (as you know) there is a lot going on in a Qt application.

Comment: Moving these resource intensive activities to different thread is definitely in my to-do list.  Btw,  thank you for your time

Comment: Np, have struggled with such issues in the past too. :D